# Formulas involving the square of a norm

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

Why does $$\|x-y+\alpha z\|^2=\|x-y\|^2+2\alpha\langle x-y,z\rangle+\alpha^2 \|z\|^2$$

but

$$\|x-z+\theta z-\theta y\|^2=\|x-z\|^2+2\theta\langle x-z,z-y\rangle +\theta^2 \|z-y\|^2?$$

Why is there a $-$ before the inner product in the 1st case and a $+$ in the 2nd case?

Comment: Neither of the equalities above are correct. Expand correctly using $\|x\|^2 = \langle x , x \rangle$ and you will get the correct result.

Comment: I edited. Is it ok now? So, all I had to do is to check inner product?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume we're in a real inner product space, $x, y, z$ are vectors and $\alpha, \theta$ are scalars, then

\begin{align*}
\|x - y + \alpha z\|^2 &= \langle (x - y) + \alpha z, (x - y) + \alpha z \rangle \\
&= \langle x - y, x - y \rangle + \langle x - y, \alpha z \rangle + \langle \alpha z, x - y \rangle + \langle \alpha z, \alpha z \rangle \\
&= \|x - y\|^2 + 2\alpha \langle z, x - y \rangle + \alpha^2 \|z\|^2
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\|x - z + \theta z - \theta y\|^2 &= \langle (x - z) + \theta (z - y), (x - z) + \theta (z - y) \rangle \\
&= \langle x -z, x - z \rangle + \theta \langle x - z, z - y \rangle + \theta \langle z - y, x - z \rangle + \langle \theta (z - y), \theta (z - y) \rangle \\
&= \|x - z\|^2 + 2\theta \langle x - z, z - y \rangle + \theta^2 \|z - y\|^2.
\end{align*}